# Unable to generate Credit Memo in magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to generate a credit memo i have two question.

1. Whenever i try to create credit memo by pressing refund offline button it show error lik e"Maximum amount available to refund is $XXX" no matter what i fill in.![enter image description here][1]
2. What is the difference between adjustment refund and adjustment fee. All i understand is if we want to deduct some amount as processing fee we can write under adjustment refund then that amount  will get deducted from total paid. But what is then refund adjustment for??

Attached screen shot 
1. "https://imageshack.com/i/nhs8s7p"
2. "http://imageshack.com/a/img534/8696/3t2e.png"

Answer (score 9):

1. **Adjustment Refund:** Amount to be added on the total amount refunded.
2. **Adjustment Fee:** Amount to be subtracted from the total amount refunded.

Take example your customer bought 2 chocolate each costing $5. However he/she wants to return one. In that case you have to return $5 which is correct mathematically (and this is what default magneto calculation shows you). But, you can change mind as business man, like

1. If you feel to giving return $6, write $1 in Adjustment Refund.
2. If you feel to give return $4, write $1 in Adjustment Fee.

"Maximum amount available to refund is $XXX" means you can not refund more than $10. In above example, you can not write more than $5 in Adjustment Refund.

Make sense? If yes, please mark answer as accepted.

Thanks